# Kickstarter Script to Extract Parameters from Commandline

Tags: bash, sed, centos, kickstarter

I am trying to customize the kickstarter script to extract the parameters from the user during the pre-installation process.
The format of the command is:

```
raidtype HAtype partitionSize
```

*i.e. raid1 hanode 2048* or *radi1 hanode 4096* and so on

However, the script is not running during installtion. I have narrowed it down to the *HANODE_SIZE* parameter.

```
#--- Pre-installation script
%pre --interpreter /bin/sh

# Extract command line parameters
NORAID=`grep noraid /proc/cmdline`
RAID1=`grep raid1 /proc/cmdline`
RAID5=`grep raid5 /proc/cmdline`
HANODE=`grep hanode /proc/cmdline`
HANODE_SIZE=`sed 's/.*hanode *\([0-9]*\).*/\1/'`
if [ -z "${HANODE_SIZE}" ]; then
    HANODE_SIZE="2048"
fi
```

When I get rid of the *HANODE_SIZE*, the installation is successful (obviously without the ability to specify the partition size). However when I include the statement that contains the *sed* command the installation stalls during the executaion of the kickstarter script.
Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my *sed* statement?

Comment: can you show the string/data on which you are trying this sed command? i mean, the <something>hanode <numbers><something> part.

Comment: Sure. The string that I type during the installation process is __raid1 hanode 4096__

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I eventually noticed the issue.
the *sed* command also required to use the command line file. The following eventually worked:

```
HANODE_SIZE=`sed 's/.*hanode *\([0-9]*\).*/\1/' /proc/cmdline`
```